# How to get the total result of sales by cpf?

Tags: javascript

I would like to add up the total sales by CPF, I managed to separate the CPF but I blanked out how to do the sum now, see my code below

```
 var vendas = [{cpf: "14382435021", amount: 34.5 }, { cpf: "79785337006", amount: 12 }, { cpf: "79785337006", amount: 23.16 }, { cpf: "14382435021", amount: 46.4 }, { cpf: "88835414059", amount: 26.2 }, { cpf: "88835414059", amount: 199.9 }, { cpf: "79785337006", amount: 18.16 } ]

var resultados = {};
for(var i = 0; i < vendas.length; i++){
    if(vendas[i].cpf){
        if(!resultados[vendas[i].cpf]){
            resultados[vendas[i].cpf] = []
        }
        resultados[vendas[i].cpf].push(vendas[i]);
    }
}

console.log(resultados)
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to add up all the `cpf` and `amount` into one object?

Comment: I want to add all the Amount of each CPF, for example, if there are 3 equal CPF, I have to display the total sum of the Amout, got it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script>
    var vendas = [{cpf: "14382435021", amount: 34.5 }, { cpf: "79785337006", amount: 12 }, { cpf: "79785337006", amount: 23.16 }, { cpf: "14382435021", amount: 46.4 }, { cpf: "88835414059", amount: 26.2 }, { cpf: "88835414059", amount: 199.9 }, { cpf: "79785337006", amount: 18.16 } ]

    var result = [];
    vendas.reduce(function(res, value) {
        if (!res[value.cpf]) {
            res[value.cpf] = { cpf: value.cpf, amount: 0 };
            result.push(res[value.cpf])
        }
        res[value.cpf].amount += value.amount;
        return res;
    }, {});

    console.log(result)

</script>
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much... I'm still a junior dev, you helped me a lot

Comment: You are most welcome. Happy that it helped you. Please mark the answer as accepted. @WPfan